# Existence of nonzero real number $r$ such that $\pi^r$ is rational

Tags: calculus

So far I couldn't find any related post of the title which is

> Is there a nonzero real number $r$ such that $\pi^r$ is rational?

Is this a know problem? Or a corollary of some theorem?

Comment: A much more difficult, to my knowledge unsolved, problem is whether or not there exist any  such *algebraic* $x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: $x\mapsto \pi^x$ is a continuous function.

Or, if you want to go another way:

**Hint**:

Pick any rational number $q > 0$, and try to solve the equation
$$\pi^x = q$$ by first taking the logarithm of both sides. Note that you can use the fact that $\log(a^b)=b\cdot \log(a)$.

Comment: If we're being pedantic, the hint only works with certain definitions of log. I'm a bit doubtful that OP uses one of those definitions